# TableView Swipe Action Button change after clicked

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I want to change the delete swipe action after clicked or swiped. For example, if I clicked delete I want to change delete to Confirm after confirm clicked or swiped then I want to clear that row. How can I do that any idea?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowAction.Style.default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        if let silinecekAktivite = self.aktivitelerListesi?[indexPath.row] {
            
            do {
                
                try self.realm.write {
                    self.realm.delete(silinecekAktivite.odemeler)
                    self.realm.delete(silinecekAktivite)
                }
                
            } catch {
                print("Aktiviteyi Silerken Hata Meydana Geldi : \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    return [delete]
}
```

[image]. [image]

Comment: To display non-destructive action as "Confirm", Why don't you present `UIAlertController` on tap of 'delete' row action and ask for consent.

Comment: How can i use that can you give me an example ?

Comment: Just posted an example, check it.

Comment: Thank you for example but I have to do this way.Showing alert is not In option for now.